# Angular js passing a variable from a parent directive to a child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives. A parent and a child. I want to pass a variable to the parent directive and have it accessible to multiple children. Here are the directives:

```
directives.directive('supNavDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",    //declare by element
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            navtree: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.returnNavTree=function(){
                return $scope.navtree
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    }
})


directives.directive('collection', function () {
    return {
        require:"supNavDirective",
        restrict: "E",    //declare by element
        link: function (scope, element, attrs,superDir) {
         scope.collection = superDir.returnNavTree()
        },
        template: "<ul class=\"nav nav-list tree\"><member ng-repeat=\"member in collection\" member=\"member\"></member></ul>"
    }
})
```

Here's the html:

```
<superNavDirective collection navtree="analyticsNavTree"></superNavDirective>
```

The child directive does not appear to get the variable. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the correct syntax to "require" the parent controller is:

```
require:"^supNavDirective"
```

Second, you must add `returnNavTree` method to the controller instance itself (instead of `$scope`) to access it from the child directive, like this:

```
...
controller: function ($scope, $element) {
  this.returnNavTree = function(){
    return $scope.navtree
  }
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. Your answer coincides with the documentation. I am new to angular and feeling a bit lost. I don't understand why the child directive in my example fails to render the parent message in my example. Here is a plunker showing what I am trying to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/9bzdrfuurTYYFJsxVKgG

Comment: Hi, glad it helps. For the new issue, I suggest you add a new question instead with proper title & description.